# How can I check if number is out specified hexa range?

Tags: lex

How can I write regular expression that recognize any expression from this form:  `"\xdd"` while `dd` represents hexadecimal number out of the range 00-7F ?

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions do  not express numerical ranges, but sequences of characters in a character set. You have to express those ranges one character at a time.

So the hex digits are `[0-9A-F]` which describes the set of characters for one digit using the two ranges `[0-9]` and `[A-F]` (you'd also have to decide if lower case letters are permitted). For two digits you'd have to notice that the first digit is of a shorter range using only `[0-7]`. The combined result would be:

```
[0-7][0-9A-Fa-f]
```

Putting the other symbols in place we could get:

```
\\x[0-7][0-9A-Fa-f]
```

<sub>(Assuming \ is a meta-character that needs escaping).</sub>